# Does AWS educate account support create peering connection between two vpc?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Does AWS educate account support to create a peering connection between two VPC?
Please help to find these

Answer (score 0):

EC2 Limitations are below for the educations account, VPC peering is not mentioned so it should be supported:

```
Starter Accounts support only following instance types:
"t2.small","t2.micro","t2.nano","m4.large","c4.large","c5.large
","m5.large","t2.medium","m4.xlarge","t2.nano","c4.xlarge","c
5.xlarge","t2.2xlarge","m5.2xlarge","t2.large","t2.xlarge","m5.
xlarge "
No Spot Instances supported
No Reserved Instances purchasessupported
No NAT Gateway, VPN Gateways, VPN Connectionso r
Customer Gateways supported
No Marketplace EC2 supported
No Scheduled EC2 instances supported
No Spot Fleet supported
```

Reference
https://s3.amazonaws.com/awseducate-starter-account-services/AWS_Educate_Starter_Accounts_and_AWS_Services.pdf

Comment: But i tried to create a vpc peering between two vpc from my educate account..it let me create but access was denied wnen i tried to accept the peering for receiver vpc ... its says permission is enabled please contact your admin

Answer (score 0):

The list of what is allowed on AWS Educate Starter Account is below:

- [AWS Services Supported with AWS Educate Starter Account](https://s3.amazonaws.com/awseducate-starter-account-services/AWS_Educate_Starter_Accounts_and_AWS_Services.pdf)

Even though the VPC peering is not listed in the pdf, VPC peering is **supported**.

Comment: But i tried to create a vpc peering between two vpc from my educate account..it let me create but access was denied wnen i tried to accept the peering for receiver vpc ... its says permission is enabled please contact your admin

Comment: @niamun Maybe its in a specific classroom? I tested it when making the answer, and I haven't observed the issue. Maybe if you describe exactly how and what steps you perform to make the VPC it will be better. You can do it in new question. Btw, if any of the answers here was useful, acceptance of one of them would be appreciated.